# Question on $\mathrm{Ad}(SL(3,\mathbb R))$

Tags: lie-groups

The following question appears in an example in  page 116, Representation theory of semisimple groups, A. W. Knapp.

Consider $G=\mathrm{Ad}(SL(3,\mathbb R))$.
It is a subgroup of $GL(8,\mathbb C)$. 
Let $U$ be the compact real form of $G$.
Then $U$ is isomorphic to  $SU(3)/\mathbb Z_3$.

Here $\mathbb Z_3$ is the foundamental group of $U$.
Is $Z_3=\{0,1,2\}$?

Here $U$ is the analytic subgroup of $\mathfrak{u}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus i\mathfrak{p}$. Can we  obtain $U$ via $SU(3)$ and the map $\mathbb{Ad}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One identifies $\mathbb{Z}_3$ with the center of $SU(3)$, namely $$Z(SU(3))=\{\zeta I_3:\zeta^3=1\}.$$

I assume that you mean $G=Ad(SL_3(\mathbb{C}))$. Assuming this, we have the adjoint representation $$Ad:SL_3(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow GL(\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})).$$ Its kernel is $Z(SL_3(\mathbb{C}))=Z(SU(3))\cong\mathbb{Z}_3$. Therefore, the image of $SU(3)$ under $Ad$ is a closed Lie subgroup of $GL(\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C}))$ isomorphic to $SU(3)/\mathbb{Z}_3$.